# How to get array items in PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

Hi I have this following code to get shipping methods from WooCommerce.

```
        global $woocommerce;
        $cart = wc()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
        $sm =  wc()->shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package($cart);

        return $sm;
```

and the result will return me an array like this:

[image]

how do I foreach it to get the data from rate array? and the value I want are id,label and method_id?

print_r($sm); exit;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contents] => Array
                (
                )

            [contents_cost] => 0
            [applied_coupons] => Array
                (
                )

            [user] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                )

            [destination] => Array
                (
                    [country] => SG
                    [state] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [address] => 
                    [address_2] => 
                )

        )

    [rates] => Array
        (
            [international_delivery] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
                (
                    [id] => international_delivery
                    [label] => International Flat Rate
                    [cost] => 10
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [method_id] => international_delivery
                )

            [table_rate-5 : 7] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
                (
                    [id] => table_rate-5 : 7
                    [label] => Registered Mail
                    [cost] => 0
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [method_id] => table_rate
                )

            [table_rate-5 : 8] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
                (
                    [id] => table_rate-5 : 8
                    [label] => Non-Registered Mail
                    [cost] => 0
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [method_id] => table_rate
                )

            [table_rate-5 : 9] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
                (
                    [id] => table_rate-5 : 9
                    [label] => Courier
                    [cost] => 0
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [method_id] => table_rate
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: is that a JSON object?

Comment: Yep it is. it will return as json as shown in the pic. i want it to retun like id=>$value->id , label => $value->label , method_id=>$value->method_id as such. apparently im very bad at arrays and multi loops please help :)

Comment: What you have there is not an array. Is a javascript string representation of an array, so you have to convert it back to a PHP using json_decode as @parag was suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($sm['rates'] as $key => $value)
{
    $method = array();
    $method['label'] = $value->label;
    $method['method'] = $value->method_id;
    $method['id'] = $value->id;
    $shippingMethods[] = $method;
}
return $shippingMethods;
```

Comment: erm i try add `return array(id=>$value->id , label => $value->label , method_id=>$value->method_id);` but it return null and in the picture there is 5 shipping methods. is there something missing?

Comment: let me update the code which will return all methods

Comment: erm now it only return me bracket [] empty data @Mitul

Comment: Can you please put jsonstring instead of image so i will copy and check.

Comment: Done added the string

Comment: hmmm this is weird i have no idea what is this woocommerce return me it looks like json cos im using a jsonview extension on google chrome.

`$sm =  wc()->shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package($cart);`

Comment: I have check the function it return the array not the json so can you please try `$sm` instead of the `$array` and try

Comment: ok im confuse which var change to $sm cos i did try just now but null. please update your code again. its confusing

Comment: Ok just do `print_r($sm); exit;` after the `$sm = wc()->shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package($cart);` and let me know what is the outout

Answer (score 2):

It look like a JSON object, user json_decode() function to convert. Visit bellow link for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php